# Is there a list of the 'levels allowed' range for joining public games of a particular quest and difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

As I've progressed through nightmare, I've noticed that public quests past a certain point are not available for me to join despite being well beyond that quest(currently I am able to join only up to "Trailing the Coven" on Nightmare despite clearing that act). I assume this is because I am not within the listed range of levels allowed for those quests.

So, is there a list of these level requirements so that I may know how much further I must level for my quest progress to be in sync with the public games I can join?

Comment: +1 Couldn't find any on google :/ Seems noone made. And It just shows the ones you can actually join so it's impossible to list at once, gotta level and write down.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL perhaps this calls for a community wiki?

Comment: Unfortunately, this data is now historical since Diablo 3 changed its difficulty levels.   http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-difficulty

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Normal difficulty

### Act 1

1. The Fallen Star: **1-6**
2. The Legacy of Cain: **1-9**
3. A Shattered Crown: **2-10**
4. Reign of the Black King: **4-13**
5. Sword of the Stranger: **5-13**
6. The Broken Blade: **6-14**
7. The Doom in Wortham: **8-16**
8. Trailing the Coven: **8-16**
9. The Imprisoned Angel: **12-20**
10. Return to New Tristram: **12-20**

### Act 2

1. Shadows in the Desert: **12-20**
2. The Road to Alcarnus: **13-21**
3. City of Blood: **14-22**
4. A Royal Audience: **15-23**
5. Unexpected Allies: **15-24**
6. Betrayer of the Horadrim: **17-25**
7. Blood and Sand: **18-26**
8. The Black Soulstone: **18-26**

### Act 3

1. The Siege of Bastion's Keep: **21-29**
2. Turning the Tide: **22-30**
3. The Breached Keep: **23-31**
4. Tremors in the Stone: **23-31**
5. Machines of War: **23-31**
6. Siegebreaker: **24-32**
7. Heart of Sin: **24-32**

### Act 4

1. Fall of the High Heavens: **25-33**
2. The Light of Hope: **26-34**
3. Beneath the Spire: **27-35**
4. Prime Evil: **28-36**

## Nightmare difficulty

### Act 1

1. The Fallen Star: **29-35**
2. The Legacy of Cain: **31-36**
3. A Shattered Crown: **31-37**
4. Reign of the Black King: **33-38**
5. Sword of the Stranger: **33-39**
6. The Broken Blade: **34-39**
7. The Doom in Wortham: **35-41**
8. Trailing the Coven: **35-41**
9. The Imprisoned Angel: **38-43**
10. Return to New Tristram: **38-43**

### Act 2

1. Shadows in the Desert: **38-43**
2. The Road to Alcarnus: **39-44**
3. City of Blood: **39-45**
4. A Royal Audience: **40-45**
5. Unexpected Allies: **41-46**
6. Betrayer of the Horadrim: **41-47**
7. Blood and Sand: **42-47**
8. The Black Soulstone: **42-47**

### Act 3

1. The Siege of Bastion's Keep: **44-49**
2. Turning the Tide: **45-50**
3. The Breached Keep: **45-51**
4. Tremors in the Stone: **45-51**
5. Machines of War: **45-51**
6. Siegebreaker: **46-51**
7. Heart of Sin: **46-51**

### Act 4

1. Fall of the High Heavens: **47-52**
2. The Light of Hope: **47-53**
3. Beneath the Spire: **48-53**
4. Prime Evil: **49-54**

## Hell difficulty

### Act 1

1. The Fallen Star: **49-52**
2. The Legacy of Cain: **50-53**
3. A Shattered Crown: **51-53**
4. Reign of the Black King: **51-54**
5. Sword of the Stranger: **52-54**
6. The Broken Blade: **52-55**
7. The Doom in Wortham: **53-55**
8. Trailing the Coven: **53-55**
9. The Imprisoned Angel: **54-57**
10. Return to New Tristram: **54-57**

### Act 2

1. Shadows in the Desert: **54-57**
2. The Road to Alcarnus: **54-57**
3. City of Blood: **55-57**
4. A Royal Audience: **55-58**
5. Unexpected Allies: **55-58**
6. Betrayer of the Horadrim: **56-58**
7. Blood and Sand: **56-59**
8. The Black Soulstone: **56-59**

### Act 3

1. The Siege of Bastion's Keep: **57-60**
2. Turning the Tide: **57-60**
3. The Breached Keep: **58-60**
4. Tremors in the Stone: **58-60**
5. Machines of War: **58-60**
6. Siegebreaker: **58-60**
7. Heart of Sin: **58-60**

### Act 4

1. Fall of the High Heavens: **58-60**
2. The Light of Hope: **59-60**
3. Beneath the Spire: **59-60**
4. Prime Evil: **59-60**

## Inferno difficulty

Inferno difficulty isn't available until you reach level 60.

Answer (score 1):

[The Diablo 3 Database](http://d3db.com) has the "levels allowed" range for each difficulty and quest on the respective quest page. For example, the first quest in the game, [The Fallen Star](http://d3db.com/quest/i/the-fallen-star/66) has the following ranges listed on the right side of the page.

> Normal Levels: 1-6
>   Nightmare Levels: 29-34
>   Hell Levels: 49-52
>   Inferno Level: 60

Answer (score -1):

You can't start Nightmare until at least Level 25 & kill Diablo.

Hell require Lv50. (beat Diablo(nightmare) 
Inferno require lv60.. of course you need beat Diablo(hell)

Comment: This isn't really answering the question.