# D3 Unable to join Act 2 public game on Hell difficulty

Tags: diablo-iii

I've got a lvl52 Wizard, with whom last night I've finished Act1 on Hell difficulty. I was able to do that in a public game. Now I'd like to join a public game for Act2, but its greyed out :( Are there level restrictions for acts, within the Hell difficulty?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of level restrictions for all modes:

[Is there a list of the 'levels allowed' range for joining public games of a particular quest and difficulty?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69664/is-there-a-list-of-the-levels-allowed-range-for-joining-public-games-of-a-part)

So you should not be able to join Act II on Hell with your current level.

Comment: You can create a game and turn that into a public game though, that way you'll be able to play a public game outside of the defined range.